# How can I get line numbers for erroneous references from biber?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, warnings

I got my girlfriend to using LaTeX for her Bachelor's thesis and she really likes it. However she still makes mistakes here and there. Normally I can fix them quite easily for her. But this one drives me crazy:

```
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '[' (section 0)
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '1' (section 0)
```

The TEX file is huge so spotting this by chance is not easy. I tried searching the whole document for `{1}`, `{[}`, and with regexes that try to be a little smarter than literal search. I only find a few `[1]` which are correct but apart from that absolutely nothing that could explain the warning.

The BLG file isn't much more informative either:

```
[786] Utils.pm:304> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '[' (section 0)
[787] Utils.pm:304> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '1' (section 0)
```

Output: [pdflatex](https://pastebin.com/3REqVx2K), the [LOG](https://pastebin.com/52C9dWx8), the [BBL](https://pastebin.com/qsTgawMx), the [BCF](https://pastebin.com/RF1xQ9i5) and the [BLG](https://pastebin.com/CNa9ta2v).

I also tried to find out how to get biber to just tell me the line number to have a look at. I just can't find any means of producing it.

Does anyone have a way for that?

Comment: Which OS are you on? And can we see some code?

Comment: Well, biber won't be able to tell you the line number since the `.bcf` file it processes does not have line numbers included. (Biber doesn't touch the TeX source.) What happens if you run latex after running Biber? Any missing database entries should leave unresolved citations, which the terminal output from latex should tell you about.

Comment: I'm running MacOS 10.15. I updated the question with a link to pdflatex' output.

Comment: What code would you like to see? The gigantic file? Without knowing where the error lies I can't create a minimal example.

Comment: If it is a biber error then presumably it is caused by a malformatted `\cite` command, maybe something like `\cite1` or `\cite{[}` or something similar. Maybe you can find the problematic command with some guesses how the command looks, otherwise searching through all cite commands (should not be more than 100-200 or so max?) will probably show where the problem is in a reasonable amount of time. Also tell your girlfriend to compile often and try to solve problems as soon as they appear :)

Comment: Or do a bit of binary search: remove a reference in the middel of the thesis from the `.bib` file, then see if the errors occur before or after the new missing entry. If before, do the same at 1/4th of the text, otherwise at 3/4th, etc.

Comment: can you share the bcf and the bbl?

Comment: Note that on a Mac you have access to grep via the termial, making it quite easy to look for strange stuff in the latex code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, more logs added. Still interested in an easier solution.

Comment: @primfaktor can you make a small complete document with `\parencite[vgl.][]16{key2}` that produces the error you show? (just needs to be a single paragraph document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bcf-file is rather long, but it is also well structured, and you are only interested in the cite keys.

So if you search for `bcf:citekey` you get quite fast to the list of citekeys starting with

```
  <bcf:citekey order="1">goepel:2020</bcf:citekey>
  <bcf:citekey order="2">boyd:un:2019</bcf:citekey>
```

There you only have to search for `>1<` and `>[` and you find

```
<bcf:citekey order="100">lay:2015</bcf:citekey>
<bcf:citekey order="101">[</bcf:citekey>
<bcf:citekey order="102">umweltbundesamt:kyoto</bcf:citekey>
 ....
<bcf:citekey order="137">cusato:2017</bcf:citekey>
<bcf:citekey order="138">1</bcf:citekey>
<bcf:citekey order="139">cusato:2017</bcf:citekey>
```

which means that the problematic keys are after {lay:2015} and {cusato:2017} which should be not so difficult to find.

A second option to find the citation is to delete the bbl-file. Then LaTeX will warn about every undefined citation and you should see in the log-file

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update

From `biblatex` v3.17 onwards the line number warnings are kept alive even after the Biber run and should be able to tell you more specifically where the problematic citations are. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1117.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[vgl.][][254]{sigfridsson}[.]

\parencite[vgl.][]16{worman}

\autocite{geer}

\parencite[vgl.][][254]{sigfridsson}[.]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

now produces

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                1
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.


Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                [
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation '[' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.


LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


LaTeX Warning: Citation '[' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.
```

---

### Old answer

`biblatex` currently does not mention the line number for entries that could not be found if they are marked as missing by Biber. If you want to get the line number even in this cases, apply the following redefinition to `\blx@citation@entry`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation@entry#1#2{%
  \blx@bibreq{#1}%
  \ifinlist{#1}\blx@cites
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@cites}{#1}}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@cite{#1}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}{#1}}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@segm{\the\c@refsection}%
                                               {\the\c@refsegment}%
                                               {\detokenize{#1}}}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
       {\ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
          {\@latex@warning{#2{#1}}}
          {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}
       {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}%
  \blx@hook@entrykey{#1}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[vgl.][][254]{sigfridsson}[.]

\parencite[vgl.][]16{worman}

\autocite{geer}

\parencite[vgl.][][254]{sigfridsson}[.]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Then the `.log` output has

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                1
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.


Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                [
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation '[' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.


LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' on page 1 undefined on input line 36.


LaTeX Warning: Citation '[' on page 1 undefined on input line 40.
```

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1117

Answer (score 1):

I also had the idea of using binary search, only the other way around to [Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn)'s suggestion.

I put a non-existing marker citation in the middle of the document and moved that in decreasing log<sub>2</sub> steps forward or backward depending on how the order of the biber warnings changed. That way I was able to pin down two paragraphs with the errors:

```
\parencite[vgl.][][254]{key1}[.]
```

and

```
\parencite[vgl.][]16{key2}
```

With balanced parens both hard to find with regexes if you don't want to reimplement the LaTeX syntax.

I still find it sad that there isn't a parameter/tool that helps you with this.

Comment: biber warned, yes. But only naming the culprit “1”, not where to find it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you get this message only if no bbl-file exists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I was trying to re-create the issue but I now see the log has been posted, I'll clean up comments here, should be able to get the line number from latex though I think, no?